# Extract hh:mm:ss from TIMESTAMPDIFF (time, Current_Time())

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

```
CREATE TABLE Test (

id int primary key,
Present varchar(10),
Date date,
Time time
);

INSERT INTO Test (id, Present, Date, Time)
Values (1, 'Present', '2018-07-18', '10:13:55' ),
(2, 'Present', '2018-07-18', '10:10:55' );
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
FROM Test
```

Result:

```
| id | Present |       Date |     Time | TimeDifference |
|----|---------|------------|----------|----------------|
|  1 | Present | 2018-07-18 | 10:13:55 |           -127 |
|  2 | Present | 2018-07-18 | 10:10:55 |           -124 |
```

I am looking to have the difference in time displayed as hh:mm:ss not just only minutes. I have tried:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS TimeDifference
```

but this gives me the error: "Bad format for Time '-02:03:10' in column 5"

How can i extract this information from the TIMESTAMPDIFF function? I have looked everywhere online but cant find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch between time and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, you will get a **positive number**

Change the unit time to second and then convert the diff second to time.

> The SEC_TO_TIME() function converts numeric seconds into a time value (in format HH:MM:SS).

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),time))
FROM Test
```